# Mongo User.find return "Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters"

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

My Express router looks like this:

```
router.get('/user/events', verifyToken, (req, res) => {
    User.find({
        _id: req.userId,
        'signedToEvents.isActive': true
    }, (err, suc) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        console.log(suc);
        res.status(200).send(suc)
    })
})
```

This seems right to me, but it gives me error. Please explain me what i am doing wrong.
The userId is a Mongo userid.

The Mongoose Schema :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const SignedToEvents = new Schema({
    _id : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    eventSignedDate: {type : Date, default : Date.now()},
    isActive : Boolean
})
SignedToEvents.set('toObject', { getters: true });
SignedToEvents.set('toJSON', { getters: true });

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: String,
    password : String,
    age : Number,
    sex : String,
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    signedToEvents : [SignedToEvents]
})

UserSchema.set('toObject', { getters: true });
UserSchema.set('toJSON', { getters: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema, 'users');
```

The call made to the API (from Angular client)

```
  getUsersEvents(){
    //returns the events for a particular user
    return this.http.get<any>(this.apiroot + 'user/events');
  }
```

Comment: Umm, It should be `req.query.userId` shouldn't it?

Comment: No it is fine - works on all the other routers

Comment: how do you call the API?

Comment: getUsersEvents(){
    //returns the events for a particular user
    return this.http.get<any>(this.apiroot + 'user/events');
  }

Comment: what's the result when you do `console.log(req.userId)`

Comment: Right, it actually doesnt give me anything - so you are right. It has something to do with missing id. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the user ID at least 3 ways:

- QueryString
- Route Parameter
- Cookie

If you're using the [querystring](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query), the value would be available via: `request.query.userId`.

Via route [parameter](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params), it's: `request.params.userId`

Via [cookie](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.cookies): `request.cookies.userId`

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. The request has a token that is being decoded on server side. In that token there exist userId. So it comes from that.

Comment: Gotcha. Are you adding the token value on every request from your Angular app?

Comment: Yes correct. I have changed the arrangement of the routers and now it works. I use ExpressJS. Does i matter in what priority they are arranget?

Comment: No that was not the issue

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. You should answer your own question so others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that I had another express router that resembles the one in scope

```
router.get('/user/:challengeId'
```

Is the same as

```
router.get('/user/events'
```

Thanks for all your help anyway.